# Swift: `weak` reference in tuple

Tags: swift

Is it possible to create in Swift 4 tuple with weak reference?

Something like this:

```
let x: (name: weak MyClass, name2: weak MyClass2)
```

Comment: No, `weak` can only be applied to declarations, not types. Why not use a `struct` instead?

Comment: This is only theoretical question. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all a weak var must be `Optional`.
Secondly, as *@Hamish* said in the comments, you cannot define a tuple field as weak.

### Workaround

However, if you really want to use tuples, here's a workaround

**Step 1** Let's define a wrapper with a weak reference to it's internal object

```
struct WeakWrapper<Element:AnyObject> {
    weak var value:Element?

    init(_ value:Element) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

**Step 2** Your 2 classes

```
class MyClass1 {
    deinit {
        debugPrint("Deinit MyClass1")
    }
}
class MyClass2 {
    deinit {
        debugPrint("Deinit MyClass1")
    }
}
```

**Step 3** This is how we define the tuple

```
let x: (name0: WeakWrapper<MyClass1>, name1: WeakWrapper<MyClass2>)
```

**Step 4** And this is how we populate it

```
x = (name0: WeakWrapper(MyClass1()), name1:WeakWrapper(MyClass2()))
```

**Step 5** The objects objects of type MyClass1 and MyClass2 we created will be deallocated on the next line because there is no strong reference to them

```
"Deinit MyClass1"
"Deinit MyClass1"
```

Comment: Nice hack ;) BTW, you can drop the type args from step 4, replacing `WeakWrapper<MyClass1>(value: MyClass1())` with just `WeakWrapper(value: MyClass1())`.

Comment: @PauloMattos Just updated my code with your suggestion.

Comment: @LucaAngeletti Nice ;)